# How to split a string with parentheses and spaces into a list

Tags: python, regex

I want to split strings like:

```
(so) what (are you trying to say)
 
what (do you mean)
```

Into lists like:

```
[(so), what, (are you trying to say)]

[what, (do you mean)]
```

The code that I tried is below. In the site regexr, the regex expression match the parts that I want but gives a warning, so... I'm not a expert in regex, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import re
string = "(so) what (are you trying to say)?"

rx = re.compile(r"((\([\w \w]*\)|[\w]*))")

print(re.split(rx, string ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[\w \w]*` is the same as `[\w ]*` and also matches an empty string.

Instead of using split, you can use re.findall without any capture groups and write the pattern like:

```
\(\w+(?:[^\S\n]+\w+)*\)|\w+
```

- `\(` Match `(`

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[^\S\n]+\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching spaces and 1+ word chars
- `\)` Match `)`
- `|` Or
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3wvBF9/1)

```
import re
string = "(so) what (are you trying to say)? what (do you mean)"

rx = re.compile(r"\(\w+(?:[^\S\n]+\w+)*\)|\w+")

print(re.findall(rx, string))
```

Output

```
['(so)', 'what', '(are you trying to say)', 'what', '(do you mean)']
```

Answer (score 0):

For your two examples you can write:

```
re.split(r'(?<=\)) +| +(?=\()', str)
```

[Python regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ckhmrb/1)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python code](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEAXv@xWPXJrF4sWbWPoh1kPA2AZsNmwiNuC/x6K3gYGZVMsi8dRaWJNogXoip4oBV2OzMN6LK7BOPaq8ULSGOKMIsqtsepi/v8tPr95FNjcinbc9oZ0dL8PEjMMHBzsOk@WO6CGKjBCxj84EJA2xWPXHnJ5hh3nrkZmptS8)

This does not work, however, for `string` defined in the OP's code, which contains a question mark, which is contrary to the statement of the question in terms of the two examples.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?<=\)) # positive lookbehind asserts that location in the
        # string is preceded by ')'
[ ]+    # match one or more spaces
|       # or
[ ]+    # match one or more spaces
(?=\()  # positive lookahead asserts that location in the
        # string is followed by '('
```

In the above I've put each of two space characters in a character class merely to make it visible.